# Add a common string prefix to elements in DataFrame column to get pre-defined string length

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have an example DataFrame:

```
df = 

sample_id    data_sample
  1              0.9
  12             0.4
  178            0.8
  300            0.2
```

I'm trying to make a new column, `sample_id_full` with the updated sample name that appends a common prefix, which needs to be in the format of "AXXXX" that includes the sample id. The `sample_id_full` needs to be of length = 5.

The final DataFrame should be

```
df = 

sample_id   sample_id_full    data_sample
  1                A0001          0.9
  12               A0012          0.4
  178              A0178          0.8
  300              A0300          0.2
```

I've tried a for-loop to check the length of `sample_id` and append a prefix of length X to get the final string length = 5, but this seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `str.zfill()`

```
df.assign(sample_id_full = df['sample_id'].astype('str').str.zfill(4).radd('A'))
```

Output:

```
   sample_id  data_sample sample_id_full
0          1          0.9          A0001
1         12          0.4          A0012
2        178          0.8          A0178
3        300          0.2          A0300
```

Comment: if you can using `numpy` ?

Comment: `np.char.add('A',np.char.zfill(df['sample_id'].to_numpy().astype(str),4))`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution consists in using [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```
df.assign(sample_id_full = [f'A{x:04d}' for x in df.sample_id])
```

Output:

```
   sample_id  data_sample sample_id_full
0          1          0.9          A0001
1         12          0.4          A0012
2        178          0.8          A0178
3        300          0.2          A0300
```